# scroll(function() not working until page is reduced to 1279px

Tags: javascript

Any ideas why the script I use to go back to the top of a page is not working unless the screen size is reduced to less than 1279px?  I simply have a button appearing at the bottom of the screen when I scroll down the screen.
I don't have any breakpoint set up in my CSS file and the script used to work until some point.

Here is the script I use:

```
var btn = $('#backtotop-button');
            
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    btn.addClass('show');
  } else {
    btn.removeClass('show');
  }
});

btn.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, '300');
});
```

This is the related CSS code:

```
#backtotop-button
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: background-color .3s, opacity .5s, visibility .5s;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#backtotop-button::after
{
    content: url(../../Images/Assets/Icons/Toolbar/toolbar-back-to-top.svg);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}

#backtotop-button:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#backtotop-button.show
{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

I cannot share the entire HTML code but I added the button id as follows, just after the body tag:

```
<body><a id="backtotop-button"></a>
```

Normally the button I configured should appear when I scroll down the page. Now it only appears when I reduce the size of the page bellow 1279px.

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

Comment: Hi Arthur and welcome to SO. The current script you've provided doesn't seem to take the aforementioned breakpoint into account. Please include the actual button and the CSS that goes with it to the question.

Comment: Could you please include the html as well so we can debug it ourselves to try and see what the issue is? Personally I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code you've provided. Although, it's a bit odd that you set the condition to 300 (though I guess that's just for debugging)

Comment: I ran your code and it worked as expected. When I scrolled vertically for more than 300px, the button showed up. It disappeared when I scrolled back up. It also scrolls me to the top when I click it and disappears correctly. There has to be something outside of the code you provided that is causing your issue. [here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71qLcdrf/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for investigating. There might be an issue somewhere else

Comment: No problem! Be sure to post an answer if you end up finding a solution if you want, would be cool to see the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve the issue by replacing "(window)" and also "('html, body')" by "'(div.body-container)'" in the JavaScript section : )